# View's location in a scroll view

Tags: android

Ive got a scroll view with multiple Linear Layouts. Each linear layout contains some images and on click of the image some details are displayed with a box opening below it as seen in the images below.

[image]

[image]

On click of a particular image i would like to scroll the row to the top most position in the scroll view. For eg. in the image above H&R is clicked i would want it to appear on the top of the screen so that the user can read the content completely. My idea was to get all the Linear layouts position in the scroll view when the views are created and scrollto the row selected so that it appears on top. I tried

```
getLocationOnScreen(location); 
view.getTop()
```

it always returns 0. Am i missing out on something here. Or is there someother approach to achieve the same.Can someone provide some input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by getting the location of each row and when the user clicks on a particular row i scroll to the location as shown in the code below

```
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, locationCorrespondingToTheSelectedRow));
                    }
                    });
```

Not the best way to do it, but in my case since the screen is static hard coding the location was not a concern.